# Tensorboard is not showing the last checkpoint's evaluation result

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I trained some object detection models with custom data for 4K steps using TensorFlow Object Detection API, and evaluated them during the training. Evaluation is done for all checkpoints, I watched the results on the console.

However, I can't see the last two checkpoints' evaluation results on Tensorboard for some raeson. It shows the evaluation result of 3K steps, and nothing after that. I can see that evaluation is completed on the console, and also in the folder.

There are no error messages on the console when I start Tensorboard. I can see that training results are uploaded completely to Tensorboard, the only missing thing is the last evaluation results.

I tried evaluating the latest checkpoints again, but nothing changed. At the end of the evaluation I receive a message saying that metrics are recorded to summary...

The training checkpoints are saved in every 10 minutes, and evaluation takes 12 minutes. But even in this case, I expect the latest checkpoint's evaluation results to be there.

When I try to download the csv file from Tensorboard I also can't see the last two checkpoints' evaluations.

What could be the reason?

```
I0311 16:57:21.281645 MainThread program.py:165] Not bringing up TensorBoard, but inspecting event files.
I0311 16:57:21.281645 140028330256128 program.py:165] Not bringing up TensorBoard, but inspecting event files.
======================================================================
Processing event files... (this can take a few minutes)
======================================================================

Found event files in:
./CN_flow1_95/eval
./CN_flow1_95/train

These tags are in ./CN_flow1_95/eval:
audio -
histograms -
images
   image-0
   image-1
   image-2
   image-3
   image-4
   image-5
   image-6
   image-7
   image-8
   image-9
scalars
   Losses/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss
   Losses/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss
   Losses/Loss/RPNLoss/localization_loss
   Losses/Loss/RPNLoss/objectness_loss
   PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/b'cyclist'
   PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/b'motorcyclist'
   PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/b'pedestrian'
   PascalBoxes_Precision/mAP@0.5IOU
tensor -
======================================================================

Event statistics for ./CN_flow1_95/eval:
audio -
graph
   first_step           0
   last_step            0
   max_step             0
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1
   outoforder_steps     []
histograms -
images
   first_step           0
   last_step            4112
   max_step             4112
   min_step             0
   num_steps            7
   outoforder_steps     []
scalars
   first_step           0
   last_step            4112
   max_step             4112
   min_step             0
   num_steps            7
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
tensor -
======================================================================

These tags are in ./CN_flow1_95/train:
audio -
histograms
   ModelVars/...
images -
scalars
   Losses/TotalLoss
   Losses/clone_0/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss
   Losses/clone_0/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss
   Losses/clone_0/Loss/RPNLoss/localization_loss
   Losses/clone_0/Loss/RPNLoss/objectness_loss
   Losses/clone_1/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss
   Losses/clone_1/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss
   Losses/clone_1/Loss/RPNLoss/localization_loss
   Losses/clone_1/Loss/RPNLoss/objectness_loss
   Losses/clone_2/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss
   Losses/clone_2/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss
   Losses/clone_2/Loss/RPNLoss/localization_loss
   Losses/clone_2/Loss/RPNLoss/objectness_loss
   batch/fraction_of_150_full
   clone_0/Losses/clone_0//clone_loss
   global_step/sec
   queue/prefetch_queue/fraction_of_5_full
tensor -
======================================================================

Event statistics for ./CN_flow1_95/train:
audio -
graph
   first_step           0
   last_step            0
   max_step             0
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1
   outoforder_steps     []
histograms
   first_step           0
   last_step            4110
   max_step             4110
   min_step             0
   num_steps            28
   outoforder_steps     []
images -
scalars
   first_step           0
   last_step            4110
   max_step             4110
   min_step             0
   num_steps            54
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:checkpoint
   first_step           1
   last_step            4111
   max_step             4111
   min_step             1
   num_steps            7
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:start
   outoforder_steps     []
   steps                [0, 4110]
sessionlog:stop
   outoforder_steps     []
   steps                [0, 0]
tensor -
======================================================================
```

Comment: Last time I had this kind of behavior (with plain tensorflow) it was because I did not set the `config` parameter of [`tf.estimator.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) which is expected to be a [`tf.estimator.RunConfig`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig) which allows you to set `save_checkpoints_secs`. However, I am not sure if this applies in your case.

Comment: I can change the frequency of saving the checkpoints from slim.learning.train.py, but I doubt that is the problem... because even though the evaluation is missing one checkpoint in between, it should still include the results from the latest ever checkpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this on TensorBoard repo as well. They said there is no reason for not to load the event file perfectly, and told me to come here...

The correct results are sometimes seen (If there are 10-15 event files because of exhaustive testing), but mostly they cannot. I changed the frequency of storing checkpoints in order to not missing any of them during evaluation (doesn't make sense, but still tried it)

I stored the checkpoints in every 12 minutes as evaluation also takes 12 minutes. It also didn't work.

All tensorboard --inspect results look fine.

I tried different models on different computers, and I also cleaned the browser cache. Nothing is helping really.

I believe there is a bug in tensorboard.